# Openshift (oc) login to registry keeps on failing - how to start the Docker daemon?

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-online

After starting a command prompt, I normally start with login in to openshift with this command:

> $ oc login https://api.starter-us-west-1.openshift.com
>   --token=

Works fine. Up till now I then connected to the docker registry of Openshift with the command:

$ docker login -u myOpenShiftName -p  registry.starter-us-west-1.openshift.com (or :443)

Now I get this error (partly translated):

> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error
>   during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/info:
>   open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the specified
>   file. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker
>   client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate
>   that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default:
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/

Do I need a local docker running?

**UPDATE/ANSWER**: yes. On windows10 home start e.g. DockerQuickstartTerminal.

At another computer I had a similar error on Windows 10 pro with Docker. The service was started, but after I had started "Docker for Windows" the error disappeared.

My environment is Win10 home, virtual box + extension + docker toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker` command cannot work without its local Docker daemon process running.

If you want to be able to work with OCI/Docker images and not need `docker` and the daemon, for some things you can use a tool like Skopeo.

- https://github.com/containers/skopeo

There are also tools for building OCI container images which aren't dependent on `docker`.